Is it is possible for a USB device to be an XInput (XBox controller) and another HID device
I'm looking to have one physical USB connection (preferably for a RPi Pico/RP2040) that acts as an XBOX 360 controller AND allows the host PC to also send serial comms to the device.
I know that a device can be both a keyboard and mouse over the same USB port (and have done this successfully) but I believe that the XBOX 360 controller doesn't fully follow the USB HID standard so this won't work.
I also know that the Pico can use PIO to create a second USB port - but that requires then plugging in two usb cables to one device.
Thank you in advance
